# How to change shape of a word with css?

Tags: html, css

I want to change the shape of a word into a diamond shape. With an element I can do this by using `tranform rotate` by 90 deg and then adjusting width. But how do I do it with a word?

```css
.contact {
  height: 50px;
  width: 100px;
  color: red;
  border-radius: 50px/100px;
  border:1px solid;
}
```

```html
<div class="contact">contact
</div>
```

Didn't work so I tried using `shape-outside`:

```
.contact{height: 50px; 
width: 100px; color: red; 
border-radius: 50px/100px; shape-outside: 
ellipse(130px 140px at 20% 
20%);}
```

Didn't work.

Something like this but without the border: https://www.silhouettedesignstore.com/view-shape/79806

Comment: Have you tried by putting word in `div` tag and applying `css` on it

Comment: can you share the needed output?

Comment: Yes. Please see above with <div class="contact" >contact</div>

Comment: This is not possible with CSS

Comment: May be canvas will help you

Comment: Of course this doesn’t work with `shape-outside`, that has a completely different purpose. You will need something that stretches vertical “stripes” of the input “image” to different heights. I’m saying “image” here on purpose, because I don’t think you will be able to achieve anything like that with actual _text_ in HTML and CSS alone - unless you want to go with a really messy DOM, that uses a large number of clones of the text element, clips them into small “stripes”, and then stretches those individually - but I doubt the result of that approach will actually look very smooth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It **cannot** be done with CSS. You would have to check out the [Canvas API](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/HTML/Canvas) to make things like that.

Comment: Not _only_ canvas - another option is to use svg's for that sort of transformations..

Answer (score 2):

The closest thing I could get to come to with just by using CSS would be something along the lines of this, although I am not sure if this is what you are looking for:

```css
.foo {
  display: block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  margin: 30px;
  border-radius: 2px;
}

.bar {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="foo">
  <div class="bar">
    Test
  </div>
</div>
```

Using `transform: rotate()` you could spin objects around.